# Use live() with focus() in JQUERY

Tags: jquery

I have an input field loaded with AJAX. 
I need that this field receives the focus when loading the page.

How to do it using jQuery, with the functions: LIVE and FOCUS?

Comment: @amnotiam lol, haven't been paying attention, is it you posting that everywhere today or is it just the current hotness?

Comment: My system uses an old version of JQuery. 1.2.6

Comment: @Pedro see my answer for both the old and new ways of doing it

Comment: @Endophage: Nah, first one for me today. This is the new *'you should totally drop that and use jQuery'*. :)

Comment: @Pedro: If you're using `1.2.6`, then you don't have `.live()` available anyway. Can you upgrade? jQuery has changed radically since then.

Comment: @amnotiam I'll try switching to 1.4.2. The script is old and big. I'll try to make minimal changes, for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#yourfield').live('focus',function()
     {
         // do your stuff here
     });
});
```

As pointed out, `live` is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7, you should use `on` in 1.7+:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $(document).on('focus','#yourfield',function()
     {
         // do your stuff here
     });
});
```

Comment: `.live()` has been deprecated in all versions of jQuery.  One should use `.delegate()` or `.on()`.

Comment: @jfriend00 How do u keep track of the new functions added or removed from jQuery? Is there a certain list or blog that I can follow to keep myself updated?

Comment: @Songo - jQuery Blog: http://blog.jquery.com/.  Though I mostly find out about jQuery changes by reading answers here.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $(document).on('focus', '#yourfield' ,function()
     {
     //your actions here
     });
});
```

where document is before on() itself could be replaced with any parent element of #yourfield.

More info here: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean on page load like so or when the field is updated set focus to the field?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#yourfield').focus();
});
```